# $\nabla^2 A$ in terms of forms?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, vector-fields

Is there a way to express $\nabla^2 A$ in terms of operations on $1$-forms?

---

I would like to see if we can write the identity
$$\nabla\times(\nabla\times A)= \nabla(\nabla\cdot A)-\nabla^2A$$
in terms of forms on $\mathbb R^3$.

---

We know that if we build the 1-form $$A=A_i\mathrm d x^i$$ then the Hodge dual of its exterior derivative  is the 1-form with components $(\nabla\times A)_i$:
$$\star\mathrm d A=(\nabla\times A)_i\mathrm d x^i.$$

---

This opens the possibility of writing the formula above in terms of 1-forms. We can write:
$$\star\mathrm d \star\mathrm d A=(\nabla\times(\nabla\times A))_i\mathrm d x^i$$
and
$$\mathrm d \star\mathrm d \star A=(\nabla\cdot(\nabla\cdot A))_i\mathrm d x^i$$
but I am stumped on the last one. The last one should be a sort of derivative that brings us from 1 forms to 1 forms. I have convinced myself that any operator from $1$-forms to $1$-forms built by composing $\star$ and $\mathrm d $ and that contains exactly 2 exterior derivatives is either $0$ or equal to $\star\mathrm d \star\mathrm d$ or $\mathrm d\star\mathrm d \star$.

What gives?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator#Laplace%E2%80%93de_Rham_operator

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux so, am I correct in understanding that the formula above can be used to *define* this Laplace deRham operator?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs in mathematics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Laplace-de Rham operator (also called the [Hodge Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operators_in_differential_geometry)) is defined by $\nabla^2 = d \delta + \delta d$, where $\delta$ is the [codifferential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator#Codifferential) operator:
$$
\delta = (-1)^{n(k-1)+1} s \;\star \! d \star
$$
where $n$ is the dimension of the manifold, $s$ is the signature of its metric, and the operator acts on a $k$-form.  For a one-form on Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^3$, the overall sign works out to be $-1$.  So we have
$$
\nabla^2 \mathbf{A} = -\left( d \! \star \! d \! \star \mathbf{A} + \star \,d \!\star \! d \,\mathbf{A} \right)
$$

Note that the Laplace-de Rham operator is in general different from the Laplace-Beltrami operator, with the latter one being what you would get by writing down a metric, a connection, a covariant derivative, etc.  The two operators agree on flat manifolds but will will differ by [terms proportional to the curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weitzenb%C3%B6ck_identity) on a curved manifold.